# PHP: Function like array constructor

Tags: php, arrays, casting, variadic-functions

I've not used PHP for a couple years—my focus has primarily been on C, C++, Objective-C, Ruby & ECMAScript. I'm having a night of keeping my mind fresh by experimenting in some other languages.

I came across an example on PHP.net of casting arrays to an object to enable accessing it's values by key as if they were instance variable:

`$obj = (object)array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');`

As an exercise, I'd like to create a function that takes the same arguments as `array` and returns the "array" already casted to an object. Something like:

```
function o_array(\* variable amount of key=>value args like array()*\)
{
  return (object)array.call(self, arguments);
}
```

I don't know how to construct a function that takes a variable amount of key=>value arguments in PHP. Thanks in advance for the advice.

***UPDATE***
I hope the following changes in the future since I see PHP's main strength as being its flexibility and general craziness (also its weakness). Named parameters are not supported:
[PHP language meeting regarding named params among other items.](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#named-parameters)

Comment: Have you looked at `array_merge()`? - http://php.net/array_merge

Comment: I was looking for named parameters, which apparently do not exist in PHP, even though they use them in the `array` function. Bummer. I already now how to convert an array to an object, or cast an array to an object. Definitely not attempting to merge arrays. Not sure where that came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't allow named arguments so this would not be possible. array is not a function but a language construct, that's why it's the only place you can use key value assignment

Comment: Even with named parameters it wouldn't work as the function still would probably have to define which parameter names it expects

Comment: That's correct @Dracony. Essentially I need named params and a version of http://php.net/func-get-args that can access args by key rather than index. They already implemented it to a certain extent for the array function, we're just not given access to it for writing our own functions.

Answer (score 2):

A variable amount of arguments is possible with [**`func_get_args`**](http://php.net/func-get-args):

```
function f()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    // ...
}
```

But there is no such thing as "key=>value arguments" for functions. So the only thing you can to, is passing them as array (which makes the whole function kind of pointless):

```
function arrayToObject(array $from)
{
     return (object)$from;
}
```

Comment: +1
I accepted the @Dracony because it's straight to the point for programmers who come across the question in the future. You mentioned the same limitation of the language as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to convert Array to Object. If that's the case here's something you can do :

```
function array_to_object($array) {
  $obj = new stdClass;
  foreach($array as $k => $v) {
     if(is_array($v)) {
        $obj->{$k} = $this->array_to_object($v); 
     } else {
        $obj->{$k} = $v;
     }
  }
  return $obj;
}
```

So if you have the following array :

```
 $a = array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');
```

Converting it will result with :

```
 $o = array_to_object($a); 
 echo ($o->foo ); // will print 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, I think this is the most sensible way of doing it.

```
class Array()
{
   public $array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');  
} 

 //initiate an object...
   $obj = new Array();
   $array = array_values($obj->array);
   print_r($array); //will print 'bar' and 'value'   
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow you to have dynamic array contents though. The question was to be able to pass named arguments like the `array` method to a different, new method that returned an object.